# I need a translation of handwriting - Bitte aufrauneu Onna?

Tags: translation, handwriting

I found some handwriting on the sleeve of an old vinyl recording, and I'm curious what it says. I tried Google translate, but I know nothing about German so I can't figure out the handwriting from context. Anyway, image follows:

[image]

I guess "Bitte" is something along the lines of "Please", and the last word might be a name (Onua? Anna?). Anyone know?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about deciphering handwriting, where knowledge of the german language is very helpful, but since latin characters are essentially the same in so much languages, and the text can easily be translated word by word with a dictionary, I vote to close. The question ins't useful or interesting for any later visitor.

Comment: »Bitte aufräumen, Oma.« (The comma is not there in the original, but the *Oma* at the bottom is like a signature.)

Answer (score 9):

It translates to: "Please clean up, grandmother".
Bitte = Please, aufräumen = clean up, Oma = Grandmother (more like grandma actually.)

Comment: Any reason to think this is a note *to* your grandmother, or (as Jan says above) a note *from* your grandmother?

Comment: @cduston If it was a note **to** grandmother, a comma between *aufräumen* and *Oma* would be mandatory, because then *Oma* would be part of the (shortened) sentence. If the note is **from** her, then *Oma* is a signature and the comma is optional (as long as spacing makes it unambiguous, which is the case here) - so: no, there is no reason to think it is to her.